# p:ajax feature not working in Liferay portal

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, liferay

I can't get the PrimeFaces 6.1 built-in ajax feature to work when using a liferay portal. I've started with the very initial use case example, that is the one shown in the PF User's Guide documentation and nothing happens, absolutely nothing happens.

xhtml side

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText value="#{bEntityTree.text}">
        <p:ajax process="@form" update="output" onstart="onStart" oncomplete="onComplete" onsuccess="onSuccess" onerror="onError"/>         
    </h:inputText>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText id="output" value="valor:#{bEntityTree.text}"/>           

</h:form>
```

Bean side:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BEntityTree.class);

private String text;

public Bean() {
    logger.trace("bean created");
}

@PostConstruct
private void onPostConstruct() {
    logger.trace("start");
}

public String getText() {
    logger.trace("getting text:" + text);
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    logger.trace("setting text:" + text);
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

JS side:

```
function onStart(){
    console.log("onStart"); 
}

function onComplete(){
    console.log("onComplete");
}

function onSuccess(){
    console.log("onSuccess");
}

function onError(){
    console.log("onError");
}
```

According to what the documentation states, each time the input changes an ajax request is sent to the server. My understanding is that the input changes when 'onchange' event is fired (default client side event). Well, every time I type a character in the `<h:inputText>` element nothing happens. When `<p:inputText>` looses the focus nothing happens, that is, `<h:outputText>` isn't updated and any trace console is displayed on the console of my chrome browser. The only trace log I get is the one from my IDE console:

```
[TRACE] Bean:<init>():bean created
[TRACE] Bean:onPostConstruct():start
[TRACE] Bean:getText():getting text:null
[TRACE] Bean:getText():getting text:null
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing.
Any help would be pretty appreciated.

Comment: The PF documentation/showcase uses an `p:inputText`, Try `f:ajax`. It is uncommon to use `p:ajax` with `h:*` components

Comment: Along with `p:ajax` I'm using `p:inputText`, but the result is the same. Very weird.

Comment: Then create a [mcve]. Did you check for errors in the browser developer console>

Comment: The example provided is a minimal, complete and verifiable example. And there is no errors in the developer console of my chrome browser.

Comment: So you have no `h:head`? Then you must have errors in your console. And if you have an `h:head`, it is not (fully) an mcve. Did you check the if the correct ViewScoped annotation is used?

Comment: For sure I have a `h:head`, which is inside a `f:view`, and it all resides in a `.xhtml` file.

Comment: Did you debug network traffic in the browser? Does the console log the js statement? Please do some **debugging** yourself

Comment: I've just posted the solution to the problem. I knew the problem wasn't related to the code, but to some configuration stuff. Thanks for your time and your help, @Kukeltje.

Comment: I think that you better post that "SOLVED" part as an answer :)

Comment: But during debugging you noticed the ajax call **was** fired from the browser, just never processes on the server?

Comment: The ajax call was fired and it was processed ok on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've just sorted the problem out. There were 2 problems. The first one (the less serious one) is that the js callbacks are being invoked wrong. The right way to invoke them should be as follows:

```
<p:ajax process="@form" update="output" onstart="onStart()" oncomplete="onComplete()" onsuccess="onSuccess()" onerror="onError()" />
```

The serious problem is related to a missing parameter in the `liferay-portlet.xml` config file.
Well, it maybe I should haved started saying that I was dealing with a Liferay portlet containing a JSF portlet which uses Primefaces. It all implies that `liferay-portlet.xml` config file is required. And this config file has to contain the following parameter:

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

The problem is that the default `liferay-portlet.xml` file, that is, the one that the eclipse IDE wizard creates DOES NOT automatically include such a parameter. After including such a parameter, it all works as expected.

**UPDATE: The way I create the Liferay Plugin Project.**

1. New > Project > Liferay Plugin Project

   Plugin Type: portlet

   Include Sample code -> unchecked

   Launch New Portlet Wizard afer project is created -> checked
2. Next > JSF 2.x
3. Next > Primefaces
4. Finish

Steps when Wizard is displayed:

1. Portlet class: javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet
2. Next
   View template: Primefaces
3. Next
4. Finish

Major result after those steps is that file `liferay-portlet.xml` doesn't have the element:

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

Development settings:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
  Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) - Build id: 20160218-0600
- Liferay IDE 2.2.4.201507230603-ga5

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The `onStart()` vs `onstart` is indeed a PrimeFaces `p:ajax` vs `f:ajax` difference. A function vs a funcion name.

Comment: @txapeldot, [the latest Liferay Faces Archetypes include `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces-bridge-ext/blob/com.liferay.faces.archetype.primefaces.portlet-5.0.1/archetype/primefaces-portlet/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml#L8). How did you generate your portlet initially?

Comment: You are using a very old version of Liferay IDE. You need to update to a more recent version to get the latest archetypes which include the appropriate settings.

Comment: @stiemannkj1: what's the latest version of Liferay IDE and where could I find it? Bear in ming that I'm developing on Liferay 6.2 CE.

Comment: @txapeldot, I didn't realize that you were on Liferay 6.2. In that case, I recommend generating your project from the latest Liferay 6.2 compatible archetype which can be determined at http://www.liferayfaces.org.